# Setting a saved file's icon

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata

I am making a custom file type, and I would like to have my application set the icon for the file without changing th icons of other files of the same type. Here is basically what I want users to go through to set the icon.

1. Open the application
2. Push a button (opens an NSOpenPanel)
3. Select an icon
4. Save the file

An alternative is to use my very simple, built in image editor. How can I accomplish this?

A good example is an image file. If you save an image from Photoshop, the file's icon is a miniature version of the image you saved. I want it to look and act just like that, if possible. Any ideas?

Edit: The file is supposed to save NSData. It is not actually an image file, but it includes the icon image.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`setIcon:forFile:options:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-slideImage_from_to_) method of `NSWorkspace`, which will do exactly what you want.